# How to atomic increment when row might not exist?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Suppose I have `MyContext` derived from `DbContext` with a `DbSet<Item> Items`, where `Item` is defined as follows.

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Given a key, I want to atomically increment the corresponding value, where keys that are not yet in the table have an implicit value of 0. That is, atomically incrementing a key not present in the table results in a value of 1. Here is my current approach:

```
public static async Task IncrementAsync(string key)
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var item = await context.Items.FindAsync(key);
            if (item == null)
            {
                context.Items.Add(new Item { Key = key, Value = 1 });
            }
            else
            {
                item.Value++;
            }
            try
            {
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                break;
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This fails with a live-lock situation when many calls to `IncrementAsync` are running concurrently.

- What is the right way to do this?
- Should the `while` loop be outside the `using`, so that every attempt gets a new context? I tried this and it makes everything work, but I feel like I'm being inefficient creating and destroying so many contexts.
- Am I missing something about the way the context tracks changes?

My entity framework experience is basically query-only, so if you could explain the finer details of what I'm doing wrong in this code I would really appreciate it.

**Edit**
Because the selected answer doesn't make it explicit, I'll place the corrected code here. Notice how the `context` is never reused after a `DbUpdateException`.

```
public static async Task IncrementAsync(string key)
{
    while (true)
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            var item = await context.Items.FindAsync(key);
            if (item == null)
            {
                context.Items.Add(new Item { Key = key, Value = 1 });
            }
            else
            {
                item.Value++;
            }
            try
            {
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                break;
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would try a shorter context to see if that helps. I would have to play around to see what this does when concurrent updates happen, it could be that certain incompatible updates get enqueued together (easiest example being an add with a Value that isn't 1).

Comment: Have you considered a stored procedure to offload the synchronization to the SQL machine?

Comment: @Guvante I want to stay in the purely-EF world if possible (which I can do by switching the `while` and `using`) unless it's really a huge optimization to do something like a stored procedure.  This particular operation is not going to be called with any heavy volume.  Getting it to work properly with modest performance penalties would be acceptable.

Comment: If you have multiple calls of `IncrementAsync` using the same `key`, there would be a problem since `FindAsync` looks for an existing entity in the context before going to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the context to not be shared between attempts. If at all possible don't do anything with a context that had a `DbUpdateException` as if you don't explicitly clean up the context it may never return to a normal state.

I would expect the outer context to cause issues. If concurrent calls to a single key happen depending on the timing you could create a bad context setup (which would be continually ignored due to your error handler.

Unless I am mistaken the fact that the `Key` exists in the database won't remove the "to be added" version. You will end up with one of these contexts:

```
Add "1", 2
```

or

```
Add "1", 1
Update "1", 2
```

Depending on whether your second iteration grabs the first iteration's object or a fresh one.

Neither of these can succeed so you end up with a continuous error.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the given answer is to use stored procedure to do all the work like the following example. Then you can call it from the application in a single line instead of the code above.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_IncrementValue
    @ValueKey NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN
       UPDATE Item WITH (SERIALIZABLE) SET Value = Value + 1
       WHERE [Key] = @ValueKey

       IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
       BEGIN
          INSERT Item ([Key], Value) VALUES (@ValueKey, 1)
       END
    COMMIT TRAN
END
GO
```

This approach gives you a better performance and less error-prone.

**Edit:**
To call the stored procedure from C# add the following method in EF ApplicationDbContext class

```
    public int IncrementValue(string valueKey)
    {
        return this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC SP_IncrementValue @ValueKey", new SqlParameter("@ValueKey", valueKey));
    }
```

Then you can call it from any instance of the DBContext Class

Comment: Could you add to this answer how you would call the stored procedure from C#?